# Sort the items of an RecyclerView - Kotlin Code

Tags: android, sorting, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a data class that contains a member called "prio" (example beneath). This "prio" should create the order of how the recyclerView display the items -> "prio" with the number 1 should be displayed on top of the rv, number 2 beneath number 1, and so on.

Additional Information: But the user could decide which number (prio) the item should have. So the "prio" is not fixed.

**Data class**

```
data class TaskModel(

val id: Int,
val task: String,
var prio: Int
)
```

**Question**: Could you please help me to create a function to sort the "prio" and initialize this function in recyclerView as the order the recyclerView displayed the items?

**Attachment:**

Adapter:

```
open class TaskAdapter (private val context: Context, private val list: ArrayList<TaskModel>)
: RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

private val mTaskDetails : TaskModel? = null


private var onClickListener: OnClickListener? = null

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    return MyViewHolder(
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_item_adapter, parent, false)
    )
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return list.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val model = list[position]


    if (holder is MyViewHolder) {
        holder.itemView.tv_task_name.text = model.task

        if(model.prio == 1){
            holder.itemView.tv_priority.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DF0101"))

        }else if (model.prio == 2){
            holder.itemView.tv_priority.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFF00"))

        }else if (model.prio == 3){
            holder.itemView.tv_priority.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#31B404"))
        }

        //holder.itemView.tv_priority.text = model.prio

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{
            if(onClickListener != null){
                onClickListener!!.onClick(position,model)
            }
        }
    }


}
private class MyViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)

//RecyclerView Klickbar machen
interface OnClickListener {
    fun onClick(position: Int, model: TaskModel)
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
 private fun setupTaskRecyclerView(tasklist: ArrayList<TaskModel>){
    rv_task_view.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    rv_task_view.setHasFixedSize(true)

    val taskAdapter = TaskAdapter(this, tasklist)
    rv_task_view.adapter = taskAdapter
 }
```

Comment: Before you add your taskList to the adapter, make sure to sort them already. Create a duplicate of taskList and create a sortedTaskList variable wherein you add the taskList by priority. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can **sort** your `array` before passing to `adapter` as below:

```
tasklist.sortBy { it.prio }
```

Your code will be changed as below:

```
private fun setupTaskRecyclerView(tasklist: ArrayList<TaskModel>){
    rv_task_view.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    rv_task_view.setHasFixedSize(true)

    tasklist.sortBy { it.prio }
    val taskAdapter = TaskAdapter(this, tasklist)
    rv_task_view.adapter = taskAdapter
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But if I put tasklist.sortBy { it.prio } to the TaskAdapter this error appear:

Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: 
required: kotlin.collections.ArrayList<TaskModel> /* = java.util.ArrayList<TaskModel> */
found: Unit 


Maybe you have a solution for this problem?

Comment: Use `sortedBy` instead of `sortBy`. The first one returns you a new list that is sorted, while the last one sorts the source list.

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu - it is also nice one